# Javascript: Any way to change the size of a variable when it is set as an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Obligatory 'I am very new to javascript' .I'm adding a button integration for my company's website to download an executable for our clients. The integration code is in javascript. In it, they allow you to set a custom image for this button by defining a variable BASE_CustomImg.

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
        var BASE_CustomImg = 'Get Support.png'; //Optional
        var BASE_CustomerKey = 'randomKey';
        </script>
```

I'd like to be able to change the size of this image without having to export a new image resolution from Illustrator.

I have tried

```
BASE_CustomImg.width = 20;
```

I've tried setting an image in HTML and then trying to define the variable with getElementById():

```
<img src='Get Support.png' id='getSupport'>
<script>
var BASE_CustomImg = document.getElementByID('getSupport');
</script>
```

and a few different combinations of those two bits of code.

Everywhere I've found online references using the document.getElementById() to define the var and then using .width to set it to, say, 20px.

It only seems to work if I leave the code as they had original put it

```
var BASE_CustomImg = 'Get Support.png';
```

I'm assuming that the answer is probably very simple and I just can't find it. Please, any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: FYI, there hasn't been a need for `language="javascript"` for at least a decade. `type="text/javascript"` went out with HTML5.

Comment: There is likely some kind of CMS that takes that variable and uses it to set the `src` of the `img` element in its own code. If that's the case, you want to name your variables very differently so that there is less chance of collision with the CMS. So maybe `var getSupport = document.getElementById('getSupport'); getSupport.addEventListener('load', function () { getSupport.width = 20; });` or something like that. Again, hard to say without knowing exactly what's going on with the code.

Answer (score -1):

It's like:

```js
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
document.getElementById('test').width = '100';
}); // end load
```

```html
<img id='test' src='https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/200423194803-anthony-fauci-donald-trump-split-large-tease.jpg' />
```

Who would have known... CNN *(Communist News Network)* is actually good for something after all.